# Questions based on the greatest integer and fractional part functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

1. If $\displaystyle x = \left[\frac{3^{31}+2^{31}}{3^{29}+2^{29}}\right]$, then $x = $
2. If $x\left[x\left[x \left[x\right]\right]\right] = 2013$, then $x = $
3. If $\{x^2\}+\{x\} = 1$, then $x = $

My Solution for first::

(1) $3^2.(3^{29}+2^{29}) > 3^{31}+2^{31}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac{3^{31}+2^{31}}{3^{29}+2^{29}}<9$

Now My Question is How Can I prove that this expression is $<8$

Means $\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac{3^{31}+2^{31}}{3^{29}+2^{29}}<8$

(2) $\displaystyle \left[x\left[x \left[x\right]\right]\right]= \frac{2013}{x}$ or $\displaystyle x = \frac{2013}{\left[x\left[x \left[x\right]\right]\right]}$

Now I Did not Understand How can I solve after that.

(3) Using $x^2-[x^2]+x-[x] = 1\Leftrightarrow x^2+x = 1+[x]+[x^2]\in \mathbb{Z}$

Let $1+[x]+[x^2]=k\in \mathbb{Z}$

So $x^2+x-k=0$, we Get $\displaystyle x = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4k}}{2}$

Now How can I solve after that, Thanks

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: +1 thanks for your work. In your last equation, it should be $x = \frac{-1 \pm\sqrt{1+4k}} {2} $?

Comment: Thanks Calvin Lin for your appreciation.

Comment: -1 OP just posted a question from code chef.com I'm not sure if these are similar live contest problems.

Comment: Again I have seen this question on my book for Competitions.I have no idea whether this question are from code chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
   3^{31}+2^{31} &=(8+1) \cdot 3^{29} + (8-4)\cdot 2^{29}\\
   3^{31}+2^{31} &= 8(3^{29} + 2^{29}) + (3^{29} - 4 \cdot 2^{29}) \\
   \dfrac{3^{31}+2^{31}}{3^{29} + 2^{29}}
      &= 8 + \dfrac{(3^{29} - 4 \cdot 2^{29})}{3^{29} + 2^{29}} \\
   \left\lfloor \dfrac{3^{31}+2^{31}}{3^{29} + 2^{29}} \right\rfloor
      &= 8\\
\end{align}

---

Let $f(x) = x \lfloor x \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor \rfloor$

We need to solve $f(x) = 2013$.

We first note that $f$ is a strictly increasing function for positive real numbers.

Since $f(6.999) = 2001.71$ and $f(7) = 2401$, then $6.999 < x < 7$

So consider $x = 7-\alpha$ where $0 < \alpha < 0.001$

\begin{align}
   \lfloor x \rfloor &= 6 \\
   x \lfloor x \rfloor &= 42 - 6\alpha \\
   \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor &= 41 \\
   x \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor &= 287 - 41 \alpha \\
   \lfloor x \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor \rfloor &= 286 \\
   x \lfloor x \lfloor x \lfloor
      x \rfloor \rfloor \rfloor &= 286(7-\alpha) \\
   2013 &= 2002 - 7\alpha \\
   \alpha = -\dfrac{1}{26} \\
\end{align}

Which does not satisfy $0 < \alpha < 0.001$

Examining the above work, we note that
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to7^-}f(x) = 2002$
and
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to7^+}f(x) = 2401$.

So there is no solution.

---

\begin{align}
   \{x^2\}+\{x\} &= 1 \\
   x^2 - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + x - \lfloor x \rfloor &= 1 \\
   x^2 + x - \lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor &= 1 \\
   x^2 + x &= 1 +  \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor
\end{align}

We assume $x = n + \alpha$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $0 < \alpha < 1$,

\begin{align}
   x^2 + x
   &= \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor + 1
\\
   n^2 + 2n\alpha + \alpha^2 + n + \alpha
   &= \lfloor n^2 + 2n\alpha + \alpha^2 \rfloor
      + \lfloor n + \alpha \rfloor + 1
\\
   \alpha^2 + (2n+1)\alpha
   &= \lfloor \alpha^2 + 2n\alpha \rfloor + 1
\\
\end{align}

I can't see how to find a general solution, so I will find a random solution.

Consider $1: x = -3 + \alpha$

\begin{align}
   \alpha^2 + (2n+1)\alpha
   &= \lfloor \alpha^2 + 2n\alpha \rfloor + \lfloor \alpha \rfloor + 1
\\
   \alpha^2 - 5\alpha
   &= \lfloor \alpha^2 - 6\alpha \rfloor + \lfloor \alpha \rfloor + 1 \\
\end{align}

The right side evaluates to an integer between $0$ and $-4$. Let's try

\begin{align}
   \alpha^2 - 5\alpha &= -3 \\
   \alpha &= \dfrac{5 - \sqrt{13}}{2} \approx 0.697\\
   x &= - \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \approx -2.303
\end{align}

Check

\begin{align}
   \{x^2\} + \{x\}
   &= \left\{\left(- \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right)^2\right\} 
     + \left\{- \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right\} \\
   &= \left\{\dfrac{7 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right\} 
     + \left\{-\dfrac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right\} \\
   &= \left\{5 + \dfrac{-3 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right\} 
     + \left\{-3 + \dfrac{5 - \sqrt{13}}{2} \right\} \\
   &= \dfrac{-3 + \sqrt{13}}{2} + \dfrac{5 - \sqrt{13}}{2} \\
  &= 1
\end{align}

A Better Solution

LEMMA: Let $x$ be a non integer real number. Then
$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = -1$

Proof: If $x$ is not an integer, then $x = n + \alpha$ for some integer, $n$, and some real number $0 < \alpha < 1$. So, $0 < 1-\alpha < 1$ and
\begin{align}
   \lfloor -x \rfloor
   &= \lfloor -n - \alpha \rfloor \\
   &= \lfloor (-n-1) + (1 - \alpha) \rfloor \\
   &= -n - 1
\end{align}

It follows that $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor = n - n - 1 = -1$.

THEOREM: $\{x\} + \{y\} = 1$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are non integers and $x+y$ is an integer.

Proof: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are non integer real numbers. Then

\begin{align}
   \{x\} + \{y\} = 1
   &\implies x - \lfloor x \rfloor + y - \lfloor y \rfloor = 1 \\
   &\implies x+y = 1 + \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \\
   &\implies x + y \in \mathbb Z \\
\end{align}

Suppose $x + y = n$ where $n$ is some integer. Then

\begin{align}
   {x} + {y}
   &= \{x\} + \{n-x\} \\
   &= x - \lfloor x \rfloor + (n-x) - \lfloor n-x \rfloor \\
   &= n - \lfloor x \rfloor - (n + \lfloor -x \rfloor) \\
   &= - (\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor) \\
   &= 1
\end{align}

So $\{x\} + \{x^2\} = 1$ implies that both $x$ and $x^2$ are non integers and $x + x^2 = n$ for some integer $n$. In which case

$ x = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{4n+1}}{2}$ where $n$ is an integer and $4n+1$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: In first line of solution, shouldn't it be $4\cdot 2^{29}$?

Comment: @Mathematics Yes you are right. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, the inside of the expression less than 9. If it is greater than 8, then we know that the overall expression is also equal to 8. $$ 3^{31} + 2^{31} - 8 \left(3^{29} + 2^{29}\right) = 3^{29} - 2^{31} > 0 $$ The last part follows from the fact that $ 3^4 > 2^6 \implies 3^{29} > 3 \cdot 2^{42} $.  Hence the answer to the first is 8.

For the next one, note that $ [x] < x \implies [x]^4 < x[x[x[x]]] < x^4 $. Because $ 6^4 < 2013 < 7^4 $, we know that $ [x] = 6 $ and hence $ x = 6 + r $ for some $ r \in [0, 1) $. From here, you would need some casework on $ r $ to see how the expression behaves.

For the last one, let $ x = n + r $ for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}, r \in [0, 1) $ and hence $ \left\{2nr + r^2\right\} + r = 1 $. This leads to an infinite amount of solutions, so I'm not sure what you want here.

Comment: I believe that the 2nd part has no answer. Can you complete your casework?

Comment: It might not have a solution. I just meant you would need to do case work on $ r $ to proceed further.

Comment: OP just posted a question from code chef.com I'm not sure if these are similar live contest problems. I'm deleting my answer.